# getting the position of current window in java

Tags: java, position, window

I'd like to get window information (size, position) from (non-java) applications other than my own (in windows os). Is there a way of doing this in java?

Comment: There's no platform-independent way to do this. If you know what platform your application is running on, you could try to use native libraries or utilities (like `xwininfo` for X windows)

Comment: I work on windows 10 is there any native library like xwininfo for window 10 ?

Comment: No clue. I'd suggest you ask a new question about windows APIs for doing what you want.